# Build Visual Studio Project for Linux Systems

Tags: linux, visual-studio, build

Is there a way to build a project in visual studio for linux sytems? This Github repository (https://github.com/nilaoda/N_m3u8DL-CLI) is very useful for my project, in this repository is just the visual studio project files (.sln ,c# source code etc.), I cloned it in my visual studio and want to build it but not as executable but for linux system? Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [their documentation](https://nilaoda.github.io/N_m3u8DL-CLI/) (translated to English), the application is built on the *.NET Framework*, which is only intended to work on Windows-based devices.  Their documentation also states it's supported on Windows XP and up, and requires the .NET Framework 4.6 runtime, which Linux can't use.

If it was using [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) (previously .NET Core) you'd be in business, but as is, without a rewrite in .NET, you won't be able to run this or build it for Linux devices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but additionally Sir though I am not familiar with mono, can I copy the source code of this project into a somewhat new mono project which I heard can be built for linux?

Comment: @michaeljamesrojas You can give it a shot! According to [Mono's website](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/): *The easiest way to describe what Mono currently supports is: Everything in .NET 4.7 except WPF, WWF, and with limited WCF and limited ASP.NET async stack.*  Thus, if the project makes use of any of these items that are not included/limited, you'll likely still need a rewrite of some sort, though probably a reduced amount.  Take a look at the link provided to Mono's site to learn more about what it supports.

Comment: Thanks Sir, for taking the time. :D, at least now I am more confident it is somehow doable.